# put ActivatedRoute where? declarations or imports, providers,...?

Tags: angular

Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'ActivatedRoute' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
this is fault i recieved

Comment: hi, Welcome, Please post your question properly providing exact details and please make sure if you are posting screenshots ensure they do get attached - More on here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TrầnDũng I thing you add component to the modules instead of declarations or something in wrong place in your AppModule

Comment: **ActivatedRoute** is an `Injectable` service, you should add it in your component constructor not in the **Module** decorator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Need to add `ActivatedRoute` in the any of your module.

Instead `ActivatedRoute` is just (optional)property of your router configuration object, which accepts service which indirectly returns Boolean value in order decide whether this route should show or not. For example -

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const ROUTER: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ]
  }
];

export const ModuleRouter = RouterModule.forChild(ROUTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t type @ before the decorator function you will have this error message

make sure you have added character @ before the decorator

```
@Component({ selector: '...', }) -> Correct

Component({ selector: '...', }) -> ERROR MESAGE: 'add a @Pipe/@Directive/@component'
```